how to get all types of file(s) path in Rider Plugin
I have a Rider plugin that gets the local path of the opened file in Rider. It is a context menu button. It is now only able to get the path of certain project files such as C# files.
It is not able to get the path of other file types such as txt.
Below is my code
public void Execute(IDataContext context, DelegateExecute nextExecute)
{
    var solution = context.GetData(JetBrains.ProjectModel.DataContext.ProjectModelDataConstants.SOLUTION);
    if (solution == null)
        return;

    var textControl = context.GetData(TextControlDataConstants.TEXT_CONTROL);
    if (textControl == null)
        return;

    var document = textControl.Document;
    var Offset = textControl.Caret.Offset();
    var lineNumber = document.GetCoordsByOffset(Offset).Line.Plus1();

    var sourceFile = document.GetPsiSourceFile(solution);
    if (sourceFile == null)
        return;

    var fullPath = $"{sourceFile.GetLocation().FullPath}?line={lineNumber}";
    var file = solution.SolutionDirectory / "file.txt";

    
}

how to make it able to get the path of all file(s) types?
Please help and thanks in advance.

Take a look at this extension method for IDocument JetBrains.DocumentManagers.DocumentManagerExtensions.TryGetFilePath
